# Кумулятивная сумма с условиями (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

У меня есть плоская таблица без иерархий, где перечислены некие события разбитые по дням и по двум признакам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне необходимо добавить еще одну колонку, где будет кумулятивная сумма по дням, но эта сумма должна учитывать Признак 1 и Признак 2. Желаемый результат выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытался сделать это с помощью лямбда-функции, но она суммирует без учета признаков, просто по дням.

```html
AAB_test.apply(lambda x: AAB_test[ (AAB_test['date'] <= x['date']) | (AAB_test['group'] == x['group']) | (AAB_test['event_name'] == x['event_name']) ].agg({'date':'max','daily_users':'sum'}),axis=1)
```

Comment: вы понимаете, что из вашего вопроса не очевидно, как сопоставлен ваш код с вашей таблицей, а уж про формулу подсчеты вы, видимо, "забыли" упомянуть. На какой ответ вы надеялись?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот такой код будет работать

```
AAB_test['cumsum_users'] = AAB_test.apply(lambda x: AAB_test[ (AAB_test['date'] <= x['date']) & (AAB_test['group'] == x['group']) & (AAB_test['event_name'] == x['event_name'])].agg({'date' : 'max', 'daily_users' : 'sum'}), axis=1).daily_users
```